# Related product brings only one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I add the related products to the products, but only the first product come, I have added other products do not come.

I tried many query styles in the controller but this is the only way I get a result

Product.rb

```
has_many :releateds, dependent: :destroy
```

Releated.rb

```
belongs_to :product
```

Product Controller

```
@product = Product.friendly.find(params[:id])
@releateds = Releated.select(:related_id).find_by(product_id: @product)
@productrel = Product.where(id:@releateds.related_id)
```

Comment: You don't need to explicitly query on IDs if you have a has_many relation setup across classes. `@product.releateds` doesn't work for you?

Comment: `find_by` returns a single object, `where` an ActiveRecord Relationship (multiple) objects (if more than one). Is that your problem?

Comment: If use where then ı get this error     undefined method `related_ids' for #<Releated::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x000000000e11af40>

Comment: You must get the related_ids attribute for each object. Use pluck for that `Releated.where(product_id: @product).pluck(:related_id)`.

Comment: @elixir ı try this method .This method chooses the related products but I can't get their photos etc. things. I get an error.
undefined method `image 'for # <Releated: 0x0000000011bd9618>

Comment: @SebastianPalma this take related_id in array .And ı take this error . undefined method `related_id' for [2, 1]:Array

Comment: Because you must pass only `@releateds` to `Product.where(id: ...)`. `@product = Product.friendly.find(params[:id])
@releateds = Releated.where(product_id: @product).pluck(:related_id)
@productrel = Product.where(id: @releateds)`

Comment: Thanks @SebastianPalma. Sometimes these things happen. Thank you for your help

Comment: Don't worry, glad to help. Don't forget you can answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

from seeing this

```
Releated.select(:related_id)
```

i have doubt that your relationship has some issue, 
below code can work for you

```
@product.releateds
```

if both models are different and not inheriting other model , and still not working the above code you should change your relationship in following manner

```
has_many :releateds, dependent: :destroy, foreign_key: :related_id
```

if still does not work please provide your schema.